# New column value based on two columns in df and possible NaN Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I am trying to create a new column based on a condition of two column timestamps such as below,

```
def time_delta(df):
if df['a_time'] > df['b_time']:
    res = 'Early'
else:
    res = 'Late'
return res
```

or

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['a_time'] > df['b_time'], 'Early', 'Late')
```

But the a_time column sometimes has a NaN value, I want the result or value in the new column if the a_time is NaN to be NaN as well how can I do this or tweak what I have for this?

Desired Output

```
     time_a           |         time_b          | new_column
2019-08-19 22:25:26.133   2019-08-19 23:00:00.000    Before_b
       NaN                2019-08-19 22:00:00.000     NaN
2019-08-19 23:00:00.000   2019-08-19 20:00:00.000    After_b
```

Thanks!

Comment: hi, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Yuca Thanks!, I added desired output

Comment: `df['new_col'] = np.where(df['a_time'] > df['b_time'], 'Early', 'Late').mask(df['time_a'].isna())` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.isnat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnat.html) to fix it.

```py
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['a_time'] > df['b_time'], 'Early', 'Late')

df.loc[(np.isnat(df['a_time']) | np.isnat(df['b_time'])), 'new_col'] = np.NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, so run the code I have then run the code you showed in the next line below?

Answer (score 1):

You may do it with `np.select`

```
df['new_column'] = np.select([df.isna().any(1), df.time_a > df.time_b], [pd.NaT, 'Early'], 'Late')

Out[923]:
                   time_a              time_b new_column
0 2019-08-19 22:25:26.133 2019-08-19 23:00:00  Late
1 NaT                     2019-08-19 22:00:00  NaT
2 2019-08-19 23:00:00.000 2019-08-19 20:00:00  Early
```